# Which pointers dangle after delete?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

If you do the following:

```
ClassType *foo = new ClassType();
ClassType *moo = foo;
delete foo;
```

And then move along, are there still dangling pointers or not? I thought no, because you only declared one "new", and deleted it, but I want to be sure...

Thanks

Comment: Use smart pointers and the problem goes away.

Comment: it is good practice to assign pointer to NULL after delete. foo=NULL

Answer (score 3):

You created one object and deleted it.
Both your pointers still point to the memory address that was previously occupied by that object, but the object is deleted, and generally this is the accepted definition of a dangling pointer - one that points to some memory that no longer contains an active object.

There is no memory leak, and your program doesn't cause a problem *unless* you try to access the now-deleted object through either of your pointers.

Using something like std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr may help you manage the memory in a safer way.

Comment: The last paragraph is false.  It's very easy to get dangling `shared_ptr`, for example.

Comment: How do you do that without going out of your way to achieve it? If it's the case I'll edit my comment of course.

Comment: The question is: how do you avoid it?  You need special logic in order to create a `shared_ptr` from `this` (and in an OO design, a lot of the pointers to an object will be derived from `this`).  And of course, in a true OO design, many objects will be responsible for their own lifetime, doing `delete this;` in response to some external stimulus.

Comment: I see your point although I'd argue that it's not the most common case, and in the context of how pointers are used in the question the point is entirely valid. However I've edit the answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the `delete` operator calls the destructor of the given argument, and returns memory allocated by `new` back to the heap. Period. It does nothing more which would mean your pointers that were pointing to a location on the heap, just point to that memory location which has just been de-allocated. So those pointer variables still contain those addresses which it was previously pointing to. This is called 'Dangling pointer'. Now if you assign your - `moo` and `foo` to `NULL` after `delete`, you will be able to identify if your pointers point to a valid location or NULL easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Dangling pointers, yes the pointers `moo` and `foo` are invalid now since it points to something which is already deleted.

Comment: is there a way to track dangling pointers during execution? Aside from if there are enough your program will recognizably slow. edit: are you serious..? How do you get rid of foo? =| Does it stay because of moo = foo?

Comment: If you don't want `foo` and `moo` to dangle, assign `NULL` to both of them after you delete the object that they point to.

To avoid having to deal with stuff like this, avoid using pointers and declare the objects directly. If you _must_ use pointers, use smart pointers. Look into `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Spire  . . . or you can put that code in its own scope so the pointers will raise a compiler error if someone attempts to use them later.

Comment: Let me note that it sounds a little like you're confusing dangling pointers and object/memory leaks a little, it might be worth to investigate the difference.

Comment: @Spire If you're doing any OO programming, `shared_ptr` is almost guaranteed to result in dangling pointers, unless you take special precautions.  Generally, you need to use the observer pattern, so that all interested objects are informed when an object is deleted.

Answer (score -1):

*foo* and *moo* points on the same dynamic object, created with:

```
ClassType *foo = new ClassType();
```

So if you *delete* foo also *moo* is 'deleted' or it become an empty pointer.

Comment: A rather uncommon term. It stills points to the same adress than before the call to `delete`, it's just that there isn't a valid object there anymore. It wouldn't call it "empty", but "dangling".